# Node functions not breaking loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am doing a webdriverjs app and I want to check when jQuery is done on the page. Here is the methods I have but its not breaking even when the else should be picking it up stopping the loop. The loop is not stopping. I think am doing something wrong

```
isjQueryAjaxFinished: function(driver) {
  driver.exec('return window.jQuery != undefined && jQuery.active === 0', function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  });
},

waitForjQueryAjaxToFinish: function(driver, reason) {
  maxTries = 30;

  for (i=0; i<maxTries; i++) {
    this.isjQueryAjaxFinished(driver, function(res) {
      if(res === false) {
        driver.sleep(1000).then(function() {
          console.log(reason + finished);
        });
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Basically what I want that if the isjQueryAjaxFinished returns false sleep for 1 second then try again. If it returns true then go ahead. Like I said above it just keeps looping no matter if its true or false and just hits the limit of the for loop. Thanks

Comment: I doubt `.sleep()` works synchronously, so your `for` loop immediately runs to completion and all your tests to see if it's done happen in 1 second all basically at the same time.  So, if your request is not done in one second, then you never see it finish.

Comment: The .then is going after the driver

Comment: @jrock2004 right, but the sleep does not halt the for loop.  That's why there is the callback...the application goes about its business (including the for loop) until the callback gets called back.

Comment: Apparently, you don't understand how asynchronous code works.  You call `.sleep()` and it returns immediately which allows all the rest of your `for` loop to run immediately so you don't get checks at different times.  All the checks are one second from start.  You have to launch your next check from within the `.then()` handler so they will truly be sequenced or uses promises to chain them all together to sequence them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Driver.sleep is asynchronous.  The loop is continuing during the sleep call.  Once the callback gets called on sleep, the loop has long since finished.  One solution is to use recursion (note you don't need to provide a value for 'i' when you originally call the function).  (Disclaimer: code below untested...but you get the idea.)

```
var maxTries = 30;

waitForjQueryAjaxToFinish: function(driver, reason, i) {
  var iteration = i || 0;
  _self = this;
    this.isjQueryAjaxFinished(driver, function(res) {
      if(res === false) {
        driver.sleep(1000).then(function() {
          console.log(reason);
          if(iteration < maxTries) {
             _self.waitForjQueryAjaxToFinish(driver, reason, iteration + 1);
          } else {
            console.log("Sorry...tried " + maxTries + "times but still no luck.");
             return;
          }
        });
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

One advantage of this approach is that it is non-blocking.

Comment: so it runs it but it does not sleep at all and just exits and all I see in the console log is false which is from the isjQueryAjaxFinished

Comment: ok so the problem was actually in the isjQueryAjaxFinished. I was not adding the callback properly. Fixed it and now it works